# Alinhamento vertical de colunas

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Estou fazendo um trecho de código onde há 3 "columns" dentro de uma "row" do foundation 5 conforme código abaixo:

```css
.row{
  background-color:yellow;
}
.align-vertical{
  align-vertical:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="row align-vertical">
      <div class="small-4 columns">
        <p>
          teste
          <br>
          teste
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-4 columns">
        <p>
          Teste
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-4 columns">
        <p>
          Teste
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

O que está acontecendo é que não consigo alinhar essas colunas verticalmente. Já atribui o "`vertical-align:middle`" tanto na "row" quanto nas "columns" e não funcionou, também já coloquei um tamanho fixo para "row" e deixei as "columns" com "height" 100% e também não funcionou.

Alguma idéia para alinhar vertical?

**Código no JSFiddle:** [Aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/zuzrco9m/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta adicionar `display: flex` e `align-items: center;` na sua classe "pai"  `.row`

coloquei alguns css a mais para compatibilidade com browsers mais antigos:

```
display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
-webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
```

```css
.row{
  background-color:yellow;

  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  -webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row align-vertical">
      <div class="small-4 columns">
        <p>
          teste
          <br>
          teste
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-4 columns">
        <p>
          Teste
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-4 columns">
        <p>
          Teste
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Deu certo! obrigado @andrepaulo ... só fiz uma pequena alteração no CSS para perder esses atribuitos em tela menor que 640px se não ficava errado os grids do foundation: `@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
 .align-vertical{
   display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
   -webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
 }}`

Answer (score 1):

Existem varias formas de alinhar verticalmente. Encontrei essa forma que pode resolver seu problema. Veja:

```css
.outer {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.small-4 columns {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    width: /*whatever width you want*/;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="small-4 columns">
        <p>
          teste
          <br>
          teste
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-4 columns">
        <p>
          Teste
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="small-4 columns">
        <p>
          Teste
        </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```